# Unity object with dynamic lightning (NormalMap) not obeying Layers

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm currently trying to create an object with dynamic lightning on Unity version 5, and everything went ok for the point light and the normal map, but when i try to put the object in a specific layer to create my scenario, it does not obey!

It stays always on the "Default" layer, even though i put it in the most foreground layer i have. Can someone solve this for me?